# Regexp in Ruby does not give the expected result

Tags: ruby, regex

I have some strings like `2015 - THIS Test` and `2015 - THAT Test`.

I want to have the part `THIS Test` or `THAT Test` so I tried this:

```
"2015 - THIS Test"[/((THIS|THAT)\s\.*)/]
```

But that only gives me `THIS` or `THAT`.

- Why does it cut the rest?
- How to get the desired substring correctly?

I don't want to rely on just cutting the first 7 characters.

Comment: You escaped the dot. Remove the ``\``.

Comment: Oh wow... I was searching for like one hour, thank you! Make this an answer

Comment: I have :) This is exactly the opposite to what mistakes people usually make: they usually forget to escape a special metacharacter. This time, it is vice versa.

Comment: I suggest using Rubular next time, as it also has a guide on how to use regex in Ruby

Comment: Thanks for that advice but I did indeed use Rubular. It worked there because I didn't escape the dot, but it seems like I somehow failed at copying it to my script...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You escaped the dot and it lost the meaning of *any character but a newline* and started to denote a literal `.` symbol. `\.*` matches zero or more literal dots.

Remove the `\`:

```
puts "2015 - THIS Test"[/((THIS|THAT)\s.*)/]
puts "2015 - THAT Test"[/((THIS|THAT)\s.*)/]
```

Result (see [demo](https://ideone.com/L1DF4p)):

```
THIS Test
THAT Test
```